# Parsing a csv file into an array using awk

Tags: mysql, file, csv, awk

I have to parse a csv file and dump the contents of it into mysql tables.

```
# myfile.csv

# Contents
# Sample Headers

"header1 with quotes", header2withoutquotes, "header3", header4, hdeader5
"Sample Text",2,3,4,"MoreText, with commas"
"Text2 with escaped \"",8,6,7,9
"Text3",876,0.6,7,10
```

First output

```
rowid|header1 with quotes|Sample Text|myfile
1|header2withoutquotes|2|myfile
1|header3|3|myfile
1|header4|4|myfile
1|header5|MoreText, with commas|myfile

2|header1 with quotes|Text2 with escaped \"|myfile
2|header2withoutquotes|8|myfile
2|header3|6|myfile
2|header4|7|myfile
2|header5|9|myfile

3|header1 with quotes|text3|myfile
3|header2withoutquotes|876|myfile
3|header3|0.6|myfile
3|header4|7|myfile
3|header5|10|myfile
```

In the Second Output i will need custom headers to be horizontally aligned. For e.g

```
rowid|"header1 with quotes"|"header3"|header4|filename 
1|Sample Text|3,4,myfile
2|Text2 with escaped \"|6|7|myfile
3|Text3|0.6|7|myfile
```

For the second output, it can be any set of headers that i choose.
I can then load both this output data into mysql tables using load data infile. Looking for awk scripts to achieve this. Let me know if you need anything else. Tx.

Comment: Pardon the unformatted data. Still learning..

Comment: @edmorton edited the question as requested.

Comment: If you need to deal with the full complexity of CSV with embedded commas and quotes, you are probably best of using Python or Perl and the CSV modules that are available with them, or a specialist tool like CSVfix (which was hosted on Google Code at one time, but that's now shut up shop; I'm not sure of the official source for it these days, which is embarrassing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave the output formatting to you but here's how to create an array of the fields after dealing with embedded commas and escaped quotes and undesirable spaces surrounding some fields so you can then do whatever you want with them:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")" }
{ sub(/#.*/,"") }
NF {
    # replace all escaped quotes with a newline and resplit the record
    gsub(/\\"/,RS)

    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        # restore the escaped quotes in this field
        gsub(RS,"\\\"",$i)

        f[i] = $i
    }

    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        # remove this to leave leading/trailing white space:
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",f[i])

        # remove this to leave quotes around fields:
        gsub(/^"|"$/,"",f[i])

        print NR, NF, i, "<" f[i] ">"
    }
    print "----"
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
4 5 1 <header1 with quotes>
4 5 2 <header2withoutquotes>
4 5 3 <header3>
4 5 4 <header4>
4 5 5 <hdeader5>
----
5 5 1 <Sample Text>
5 5 2 <2>
5 5 3 <3>
5 5 4 <4>
5 5 5 <MoreText, with commas>
----
6 5 1 <Text2 with escaped \">
6 5 2 <8>
6 5 3 <6>
6 5 4 <7>
6 5 5 <9>
----
7 5 1 <Text3>
7 5 2 <876>
7 5 3 <0.6>
7 5 4 <7>
7 5 5 <10>
----
```

The above uses GNU awk for `FPAT`, with other awks you'd need a `while(match(...))` loop.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content for how `FPAT` works to split the input into fields. Other than that:

1. The first `sub()` and test for `NF` discard comments and empty lines.
2. The `gsub()` before the loop replaces every occurrence of `\"` with a newline so that escaped quotes aren't in the way of field splitting and the fact that this op works on the whole record causes awk to re-split afterwards so the `FPAT` is again applied at that point, assuring that the original `\"`s have no effect on the fields going into the loop.
3. The `gsub()` in the 1st loop restores any `\"`s that were originally present in the current field
4. The 1st `gsub()` in the 2nd loop just trims all leading and trailing white space off the current field.
5. The 2nd [optional] `gsub()` in the 2nd loop removes start/end quotes from the field.

and the rest should be obvious. I'm stripping leading/trailing spaces and quotes where `f[]` is used rather than where it's populated since you seem to want at least 2 different outputs, one with surrounding quotes and one without, but its your choice where either of those `gsub()`s is done.

To learn awk - get the book Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Tx @edmorton. Appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
{
    if(NR==1)
        split($0,header,",")
    else
    {
        split($0,line,",")
        for (i in line)  
        {
            gsub(/^[ \t]+|"|[ \t]+$)/, "", header[i]); 
            gsub(/^[ \t]+|"|[ \t]+$)/, "", line[i]); 
            print header[i]"|"line[i]"|"FILENAME
        }
        print ""
    }
}
```

Basically it stores the first line in the `header` array, then it `split`s each line in the `elem` array and trims away leading and trailing spaces or tabs. Finally, it composes the output string.

Output:

```
header1|text1|file2
header2|2|file2
header3|3|file2
header4|4|file2
hdeader5|moretext|file2

header1|text2|file2
header2|8|file2
header3|6|file2
header4|7|file2
hdeader5|9|file2

header1|text3|file2
header2|876|file2
header3|0.6|file2
header4|7|file2
hdeader5|10|file2
```

You can get rid of the newlines between each block by removing the last `print ""` statement.

Comment: Tx @Cynical. I forgot to mention about commas existing between texts too. Say for example: "Some, more text with,commas in between". These will be an issue right? Just ran this script on my csv files and realised my mistake. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sample: "Some text",Text,"Some text, with comma","Normal text in quotes". Tx again.

Comment: Yes, that could be an issue... Is it possible that text-with-commas are **always** enclosed between quotes?

Comment: preprocess change your field separator from commas to something not contained in your fields, tabs ,tilde,pipe ...

Comment: Yes, the ones with commas within text will always be within quotes. The ones without commas may or maynot be within quotes. So you may have words like: Text and "Text" and "Text, with comma" all in the same file.

Comment: @tomc tx. That was one line of thought. There are close to 8k and more csv files that need to be processed sequentially. The awk script is great so far. If it could be handled within it i can eliminate this preprocessing overhead.

Comment: not that is matters w.r.t sed but surely the files are independent and can be processed in parallel (probably with gnu parallel)

Comment: The script is a good starting point. Will check the quality of data once again and revert. Tx @tomc

Comment: @user676500 no, it's not a good starting point. Among other things it redundantly re-does the field splitting awk does automatically, doesn't use the builtin variables/functionality but instead hard-codes values in multiple places, runs gsub() on every field of the header line for every line of data instead of just once, does gsub()s instead of just using the right FS, doesn't use POSIX character classes, and will randomly shuffle the order of the fields. Edit your question as I suggested to get help.

Comment: @EdMorton Tx for the detailed explanation. Caught the bugs now. Honestly didnt notice it so closely. Is there anything you or anybody can suggest to do this better? Really pressed for time!

Comment: Guys have made some breakthrough. Need one help though. I want to use comma(,) as field separator for the first line and quotes-comma-quotes (",") for the rest using awk? Possible?

Comment: Anything is possible, it's only software, but you still haven't done what I suggested in my comment under your question which is why no-one's given you answers yet - we're all waiting on you to simply show us your actual input/output so we don't end up peeling the onion.